# Computer won't power on except when I remove the 2x2 connector

Tags: power-supply

My friend's computer wouldn't power on. The fans (and a blue LED near the power switch) come on briefly and then turn off immediately.

I have removed the connections to the drives and the only PCI card, a wireless card. I bought a new power supply and plugged it in, but that didn't change anything.

I am able to turn on the new power supply (or at least its fan) by shorting the green wire to ground in the 24-wire connector that runs from the power supply to the motherboard. This didn't work for the old power supply, so that proves that it was broken.

Is it likely that, when the old power supply died, it ruined something on the motherboard?

- I noticed that the processor fan turns the wrong way, pulling air towards the processor. The plug isn't reversible. Is this a clue?
- The case fan and processor fan also run quite slowly. Is this a clue?

I removed the 2x2 connector that runs from the power supply to the motherboard, and NOW THE POWER STAYS ON. Well, the three fans stay on, but there is no further sign of life. The motherboard doesn't beep.

At this point, I can't turn the power/fans off using the case's power button (even holding it down), so I use the power supply's power button on the back of the case.

Now that I have isolated which connector is the problem, is there a way to fix it? Might it be that a capacitor near the socket is broken and I could replace it?

Comment: "*I removed the 2x2 connector that runs from the Power Supply to the motherboard, and NOW THE POWER STAYS ON.*" Why in the world would you do such a thing?! What motherboard? What CPU?

Comment: "I noticed that the processor fan turns the wrong way, pulling air towards the processor. The plug isn't reversible. Is this a clue?" The fan blows air on to the heat-sync and through it.  It is functioning correctly!  Don't try and reverse it.

Comment: David: I unplugged the connector because I was unplugging everything else (devices), and nothing was working.  To my surprise, the fans finally did power on and stay on.  So I did manage to narrow down the problem a bit.

Comment: DaveL: I am surprised to hear that this is the correct direction, but I suppose both directions would work.

Comment: @user200692: You didn't narrow the problem down at all, and you may have created a new problem.

Comment: I think I narrowed it down.  Now I know the problem is somewhere near the processor.  Also, I demonstrated that the fans work and that the motherboard functions enough to power the fans.  What new problem did I create?  Also keep in mind that this motherboard will be thrown out if I can't fix it, so I didn't have much to lose.

Comment: The 2x2 cable provides power to the CPU, so of course the system won't boot, the CPU has no power.

Answer (score 0):

First, disconnect any devices not needed to get to the BIOS: hard-disk drives, CD/DVD, PCI (Express) cards except the graphic card (unless there is an onboard/integrated one)...
Then you should check for short circuits on the motherboard, or signs of it - something looking burned. If there aren't any, it's probably the CPU and/or voltage regulator on the motherboard that died. Putting a working CPU instead of the current one is more risky (as the broken voltage regulator could burn it) than trying the current CPU with a working motherboard, so you could continue with the latter step. One of these steps could help you figure out what's wrong and needs replacing.

Depending on how old the system is, second-hand could be feasible.

From [About.com](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/insidethepc/a/atx-pinout-4-pin-12v-psu.htm):

> The ATX 4 pin power supply connector is a standard motherboard power
> connector used to provide +12 VDC to the processor voltage regulator.

Check the links there for further info on testing the power supply.

Comment: sm4rk0: Thanks for the advice.  I did disconnect the devices.  To check for short circuits, I checked for lose metal objects (screws) sitting on the motherboard, then looked for burned components, but didn't see any.  There may be something underneath the CPU's heat sink.

Comment: Is the voltage regulator a visible component, or is it tiny and also hidden under the heat sink?  Is it possible to test the voltage regulator?  Can I replace the VR and not the CPU?  Why would the computer turn off if its VR isn't working?  Does the voltage fluctuate too much? ...  I don't have a spare motherboard... About.com did have some good articles... Next, I guess I need to remove the heat sink, and it sounds like I need to get into the messy thermal paste stuff.  Heat the sink with a hairdryer and try to twist it off the CPU.

Comment: First: do not remove heat sink. Second: if you decide to remove - don't use hairdryer

Comment: @user200692 (I exceeded 5 minute comment editing time) 3. VRs with their belonging capacitors and coils can be seen here: http://img.tomshardware.com/us/2004/05/21/six_dual_xeon_motherboards_on_the_cheap/asus_regulator.jpg (10 black 3-pin components). Don't try to fix it if you don't have some good experience with the soldering iron, as advanced skill is needed to replace one of them - assuming you have the appropriate replacement part(s). 4. Power supply units (PSU) have automatic shut-down system as a protection from damage due to excess current which usually happen due to a short-circuit.

Comment: I was hesitating, because I knew I might break a processor pin or something, so I haven't yet removed the heat sink.  I can't access the processor's locking mechanism, so I guess I can't look at the processor at all.  The hairdryer idea came from advice on About to people who had pulled the heat sink and pulled the processor with it.  Apparently the thermal paste softens when the computer has been on for half an hour. With a dead computer, I don't have that option.  I haven't yet pulled the processor out, and I'd be blowing air from the top of the heat sink, so it might not work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the image.  I can see them on my motherboard.  They don't look damaged, but maybe they are internally...  My question, which you answered, was that, if there is no short circuit, then would a faulty/missing voltage regulator matter?  So I think we can conclude that there is a short circuit...  I doubt that any computer store could do this soldering, and if they could, would charge more than a new motherboard.

Comment: So are we concluding that I must buy a new motherboard?  If so, must I get the same one again?  I don't see any labelling on the MB to identify it.  I'm also not sure which processor it is (I think it's quad-core).  Or should I get a new modern MB?  What might it be incompatible with?  Maybe the RAM?  The case with its fans?  Or should I get a new computer box?

Comment: As you are not sure wheather the problem is with MB or CPU, buying a new motherboard is not 100% sure solution. If it's the MB what died, you don't need to get the same, but that would be the best as you wouldn't need new drivers. You should determine either the CPU model or the chipset in order to be sure you are buying appropriate MB. If your memory is DDR3, the easiest way could be buying the new MB+CPU (supporting DDR3) and reusing the existing memory, HDD,...

Comment: A new development: Looking at the motherboard with a mirror, I noticed that the heat sink seemed not already be detached from the processor.  The thermal paste had dried out!  Is this normal, or is it associated with all the dust that I found inside the box?  I initially thought that this might explain why the computer turns itself off immediately -- that the processor overheats because the heat sink isn't even touching the processor.  But I think it wouldn't overheat that quickly (right?).

Comment: Anyway, now I could access the processor, so I removed it.  As a test, I plugged in the 2x2 connector and powered on, and it (the case fan) does stay on.  So, does this prove that the processor is the problem, and that there is no short circuit in the voltage regulator chips around the processor?  And that the motherboard is probably ok, and that all I should do at this point is buy a new processor?

Comment: CPU temperatures rise to the shut-off temperature in a second or two, so it looks that you found the problem: heat-sink not properly applied. If you are lucky enough, the CPU is fine and you don't need to buy a new one. Just fit the heat-sink in its place.

Comment: Wow, I hope this is what it is.  I guess I'll clean it first with 90% isopropyl alcohol and then apply a new layer of thermal paste.